# Close na transação com hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transações

Olá,

Preciso de uma ajuda. Estou tentando realizar uma transação no hibernate.

O problema é que, ao dar um `close`, os dados são modificados no banco, mas ocorre esse `WARN`:

> WARN [CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] Invocation of destroy method
>   failed on bean with name 'sessionCreator':
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
Transaction transacao = null;
    try {
        transacao = session.beginTransaction();
        contaDao.atualiza(conta);
        transacao.commit();
        session.close();    
    } catch (Exception err) {  
        if (transacao != null) {
            transacao.rollback();
        }
    }
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Segue o método inteiro:

```
 public void atualizarSaldo(LancamentoDados dados, double novoSaldo) {
    ContaBancaria conta = new ContaBancaria();
    HistoricoConta historicoSaldoConta = new HistoricoConta(this.historicoConta);
    conta.setCodContaBancaria(dados.getConta().getCodContaBancaria());
    conta.setNumeroContaBancaria(dados.getConta().getNumeroContaBancaria());
    conta.setSaldoContaBancaria(novoSaldo);
    conta.setAnotacaoContaBancaria("Sem conta");
    Transaction transacao = null;
    try {
        transacao = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Estou no try em atualiza");
        contaDao.atualiza(conta);
        historicoSaldoConta.inserirSaldoConta(conta);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("Erro meu : " + err);
        if (transacao != null) {
            transacao.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: você pega sua session assim Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();?

Comment: Rafael, nao estou usando assim

Comment: @IvanAlves Pode colocar seu método inteiro? Vc está abrindo a sessão em algum lugar?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto coloquei o metodo inteiro

Comment: @IvanAlves Onde vc está abrindo a sessão?

Answer (score 0):

Na Exceção diz que sua Session já está fechada:

```
Session was already closed
```

Recomendo fazer uma validação antes de fechar a Session, para Evitar que ele tente fechar uma `Session` já fechada:

```
if (this.session.isOpen()) {
      session.close();

    }
```

Comment: Fiz o if, como acima, mesmo que eu só feche se a conexão tiver aberta, parece que em algum outro momento ele tente fechar novamente. pois aparece a excessao. se eu não dar um close, isso não ocorre, porem ele buga, não deixando eu retornar nada para a view.

Comment: Em todos seus metodos que fazem conexao com o banco esta sendo tratado isso ?

Comment: Pois isso pode estar ocorrendo em outro metodo

Comment: Isso esta ocorrendo nesse metodo ao usar o commit, caso eu comente a linha commit do metodo que estou usando, nada de errado acontece no sistema.

Comment: sua conexão com o banco de dados está configurada como setAutoCommit(false); ?

Comment: Meu banco esta sim

Answer (score 0):

Você já finalizou a sessão , o ideal é você fazer uma verificação pra saber se a sessão foi aberta e uma pra verificar se esta fechada... você colocando os 2 if , você consegue controlar o que acontece nas transações do seu código.

```
if(session.Open())
{
}
if(session.Close())
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui através desse código:

```
Transaction transacao = null;
    Session sess = Sessao.getSessao();      
    try {
        transacao = sess.beginTransaction();
        contaDao.atualiza(conta);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("Erro meu : " + err);
        if (transacao != null) {
            transacao.rollback();
        }
    } finally {          
        sess.close();              
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu objeto `session` foi obtido por meio do método `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, o motivo, [segundo este artigo](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13951) e [esta outra resposta no StackOverflow global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45733794/9550393), é que as sessões obtidas a partir deste método são gerenciadas pelo Hibernate "por baixo dos panos", são abertas no momento em que você chama o método e são fechadas automáticamente logo que a transação é finalizada, por meio de `commit()`, `rollback()` ou por execução de algum DDL. Você não precisará fechá-la manualmente caso já tenha executado um commit ou rollback, que é o seu caso.

O mesmo não ocorre quando se utiliza `SessionFactory.openSession()`, as sessões obtidas por meio deste método requerem que você feche-as manualmente.